# Camera2 control image orientation

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I have created camera screen based on Google `camera2` sample, all code almost identical, the camera takes photo and saves it on the device in `JPEG` format, but I have some weird behavior.

For example, **taking photo from emulator rotates the image 90 degrees**(the image rotated, not preview), on my Huawei the image not rotated.

What weird is that **screen rotation and sensor orientation values is identical both on Emulator and Huawei**.
So how exactly the jpeg orientation is sets?

Also while exploring `CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION`

```
captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation))
```

I have noticed that **this method have no effect on Emulator at all**.

I have tried to get `JPEG` orientation from `ExifInterface` after bitmap saved, but in both Emulator and Huawei the value is `ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED`. Maybe while converting `Image`(from `ImageReader`) to `File` `Exif` tags ignored?

Maybe i need to set the ExifInterface manually while taking image, but if the values is identical what is the difference?
How we supposed to control the `JPEG` orientation?

Using this method to get orientation(from Google camera2 sample) result is 90 degrees for Emulator and Huawei.

```
private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
        return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
    }
```

using this method to get `Bitmap` from `ImageReader`

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromReader(ImageReader reader) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Image image = null;

    try {
        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
        ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
        buffer.rewind();
        byte[] data = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(data);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (image != null) {
        image.close();
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulator is a very bad starting point to work with Camera2 API. Essentially, it has LEGACY Camera2 support, with some quirks.

This said, Jpeg orientation is a very delicate topic on Android camera. The official docs explain that rotation request may apply to the image itself, or to EXIF flag only, but some devices (which Huawai did you test?) don't comply at all.

Also note that `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` [ignores the EXIF flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552197/192373), [since the very beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12950954/192373).

Comment: Yes, my main issue and confusing was that `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` ignores `Exif` data

Comment: The value `JPEG_ORIENTATION` appears to have no effect on the actual data on my Pixel 3a, too. Is there any way around this, or at least a way of rotating the image that isn't expensive, performance-wise?

Comment: @DaveNottage that's the sad fact. I wonder how Android 12 platform the AVIF image support will help with this.